# Item positioning on scroll gives a warning about asynchronous scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to position two images by changing their top margin based on the scroll position.
The margins have a max value as well.

Everything works just fine but I have a warning on the console, saying that this solution can cause a jittery scrolling effect in browsers with asynchronous scrolling.

My first question is, should I worry about this?
Also, this is literally my first few lines of javascript and I'm not sure if this solution is good enough, so any advice is appreciated.
It just looks so simple I feel like there is a catch.

I could do it by adding classes to the images and set the margins in CSS, but it would be a lot longer code I guess.
I'm trying to do this strictly with js and CSS grid, just to learn to solve problems with limited tools.

The images are in a div, which is in a grid cell.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  myMargin = 0.011 * window.scrollY;
  if (myMargin < 3.4) {   //max margin is 3.4% for myImg1
    myImg1.style.marginTop = animMargin + "%";
    myImg2.style.marginTop = animMargin / 2.7 + "%";  //myImg2 moves on a different scale
  } else {
    myImg1.style.marginTop = "3.4%";   //when the max value reached the margin is fixed
    myImg2.style.marginTop = "1.25%";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling handlers can be intensive and put performance strain on the page as they will fire far more times than your handler actually needs. This ends up causing choppy/lag when scrolling as the browser may need to repaint in response to your handler.

A common technique is to throttle or debouce the handler.

Throttle:

> only invokes func at most once per every x milliseconds.

Debouce:

> delays invoking func until after x milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced function was invoked.

The warning you are getting is actually fine, but you may benefit from using a throttled callback and increase the wait time to the max that is suitable for your needs - so least times it is called in order for it to work for you.

Demo using [lodash throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle)

```js
// only call the handler once every 200ms
const throttledScroll = _.throttle(() => {
  console.info('throttled', window.scrollY);
}, 200);

window.addEventListener('scroll', throttledScroll);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```